# Cannot reach Rails-API-Server from Android Emulator

Tags: android, rest, android-emulator, retrofit2, rails-api

I have an Rails-api running on localhost:3000. I have an android app setup to authenticate the user (login). I am using **Retrofit**. This is the setup:

```
`
    String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.104:3000";
    if(retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
`
```

I can make the calls from my actual device. Works perfect.

I want to do the same thing using the Android Emulator. And, it is not working. I went through some [android documentations](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#forwardports) and other Stack Overflow questions. I found out that you cannot reach host using the actual IP i.e. 192.168.0.104 in my case. I have to use **10.0.2.2**. Then I did this:

```
`
String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000";
`
```

Still, it is not working.

This is how I am making the call.

```
`
Call<User> call = apiInterface.performUserLogin(mEmail, mPassword);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
    ...
    ...
});
`
```

The execution seems to be failing from the **call.enqueue(new Callback()**. The callback is not being executed at all. And, I have no clue why.

**Just found out this in the Log**

```
`
08-08 18:46:12.659 13835-13835/com.example.gist.toasms E/Exception: java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to 10.0.2.2 not permitted by network security policy
```

`One of the solution was to add`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in manifest but that is only available from minSdkVersion 23. Mine is 22

Thank you!

Comment: I can access the server from the browser with (http://10.0.2.2:3000)

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, there is no issue adding an attribute that is introduced at a higher SDK level than your minimum. It will be ignored by devices earlier than its introduction. You do get a warning in AndroidStudio, but that can be suppressed if you prefer. Simply add: `tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"`

For a more complete answer, Android 9.0 (SDK 28) started disabling cleartext network communications by default. See [Android 9.0 (SDK 28) cleartext disabled](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

You have several options, in order of security preference:

- Change all network access to use HTTPS.
- Add a network security config file to your project to allow cleartext to particular domains that don't support HTTPS.
- Enable Cleartext support for the app by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the application in the manifest.

To add a Network Security File to your project, you need to do two things. You need to add the file specification to the manifest:

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" .../>
```

Secondly, create file res/xml/network_security_config.xml and specify your security desires:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.10</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```